# How to make type from nested part of another type?

Tags: typescript

I'm creating website that uses code generation for type safety around GraphQl queries. Some components in my app get part of object as prop. The type looks as follows:

```js
type ActiveOrderQuery = {
    __typename?: "Query" | undefined;
    activeOrder?: {
        __typename?: "Order" | undefined;
        id: string;
        subTotalWithTax: number;
        subTotal: number;
        currencyCode: CurrencyCode;
        lines: Array<{
            __typename?: 'OrderLine';
            id: string;
            quantity: number;
            linePrice: number;
            linePriceWithTax: number;
            unitPrice: number;
            unitPriceWithTax: number;
            productVariant: {
                __typename?: 'ProductVariant';
                name: string;
                featuredAsset?: {
                    __typename?: 'Asset';
                    preview: string;
                } | null;
            };
            discounts: Array<{
                __typename?: 'Discount';
                type: AdjustmentType;
                description: string;
                amount: number;
                amountWithTax: number;
            }>;
        }>;
    } | null | undefined;
}
```

My components maps over 'lines' property so I'd like to dynamically create or access type definition for ActiveOrderQuery["activeOrder"]["lines"].
I've tried mapped types but those only allow me to go one level deep so I could do
`type NestedType = ActiveOrderQuery["activeOrder"]`
but not
`type NestedType = ActiveOrderQuery["activeOrder"]["lines"]`
Is there any solution to that problem? I'd like to avoid writing those types by hand as they can change due to code generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took longer to figure out than I would like to admit haha.

The problem is that `activeOrder` can be either an object, null or undefined, of course the keys of null and undefined are `never` so you can't extract them.

To get the keys out, first get rid of `null|undefined` using the `Exclude` utility.

```
type NestedA = Exclude<ActiveOrderQuery["activeOrder"], null|undefined>;
type NestedB = NestedA["lines"];

type Nested = Exclude<ActiveOrderQuery["activeOrder"], null|undefined>["lines"];
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you good sir. It certainly would have taken me 20x times longer xD

Comment: It's kinda separate question but do You have any ideas how to convert Nested from array type to type consisting single object?
EDIT. nevermind Nested[0] works even if there are no objects in types :p